# Disable ACPI power button

Tags: c++, shutdown, acpi

is there any simple way to disable processing ACPI power button events (Shutdown) temporarily using the Windows API in Visual C++, so the user isn't able to shut down the computer using the power button?

Comment: LOL, are you trying to play a practical joke on somebody?

Answer (score 1):

In short, No.

A slightly longer explanation states that the ACPI spec has a statement (to paraphrase) "pressing and holding the power button for 4 seconds must turn the power off".

Comment: I know and that's ok. All I want is to disable the regular shutdown procedure windows initiates when someone presses the power button.

Comment: In that case, I guess you could edit the power scheme programmatically - I'm interested in the use case for this, mind...

Comment: Note: Some BIOSes allow you to disable the "press and hold for 4 seconds" behavior.

Comment: I have the same question as op. Waiting for more answers.

Answer (score 1):

you probably would have to override embedded controller's _qxx method in DSDT namespace to suppress the BIOS sending a notify(80) to the OS acpi driver, which then shuts down the system programatically. This is what triggers the shutdown sequence. ACPI tables are cached in the registry on every boot and the same registry mechanism also supports overriding.